# Symfony ChoiceType deep label customization

Tags: symfony

I want to customize my EntityType's choice labels highly, like creating a table with multiple attributes of my model.

**So I want to access my choices class attributes. The choices are my entities of class `MyClass` through the `EntityType`. How can I do so in twig?**

Currently I do it like this:

**1.** in my FormClass I `json_encode` all fields I need in my label

**2.** in my template I `json_decode` these information and display according

IN CODE:

**1.**

```
$builder
    ->add('field', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => MyClass::class,
        'multiple' => false,
        'expanded' => true,
        ],
        'choice_label' => function (MyClass $myClass) {
            $data = [
                'name' => $myClass->getName(),
                'description' => $myClass->getDescription(),
            ];

            return json_encode($data);
        },
    ])
```

**2.**

```
{% block my_form_widget %}
    ...
    {# form is my 'field' FormView of the EntityType #}

    {% for child in form %}
        {# child is a FormView, one choice of my EntityType #}
        {# child.vars.data is boolean as its a checkbox #}

        {% set data = child.vars.label|json_decode %}
        create some complex html here, like tables
        ...
    {% endfor %}
...
{% endblock %}
```

Working. But is there a better way?

Thanks,
Kim

Comment: why the json? you could custom without it..

Comment: @hoover_D how? I do not have access to the entity of the choice in the template. So how can I access my entity's (in my case MyClass) attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it, here is an example of how to access the data of your EntityType's choices in twig. You can check the `child.parent.vars.choices` list.

```
{% block my_form_widget %}
    ...
    {# form is my 'field' FormView of the EntityType #}

    {% for child in form %}
        {# child is a FormView, one choice of my EntityType #}
        {# child.vars.data is boolean as its a checkbox #}

        {% for choice in child.parent.vars.choices if choice.value == child.vars.value %}

            {{ choice.data.name }} {# contains MyClass name #}
            {{ choice.data.description }} {# contains MyClass description #} 

        {% endfor %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
...
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Symfony form (or form field, which is just a form of its own) that is mapped to an entity, you always have access to the underlying data in `form.vars.data`. So in this case, `form.vars.data` would either be `null` or an instance of `MyClass`.

For ease of use in your template, you might do something like:

```
{% set my_object = form.field.vars.data %}
{% if my_object %}
    {{ my_object.getName() }}
    {{ my_object.getDescription() }}
{% endif %}
```

Thus there is no need to re-encode your entity data for the view layer, since it's always already available.

If you are working with an `EntityType` and want to access the properties of each choice's entity, they are available as well in the `choices` array:

```
{% for choice in form.field.vars.choices %}
    {{ choice.data.getName() }}
    {{ choice.data.getDescription() }}
{% endfor %}
```

A nice trick when you're trying to access any form data and aren't sure where to look is to temporarily add a line to your template like:

```
{{ dump(form.field) }}
```

This will allow you to look through the available data and see what all is available. Note that it requires the Twig debug extension to be enabled, and XDebug to be enabled in PHP in order to make the output look nice.

Comment: This is not true for EntityType's choices. Yes, it is for EntityType itself, but not for all its choices which are handled/rendered as form children, but there you cannot access the data via `vars.data`, that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: Your question's title says `ChoiceType`; it wasn't clear that you were specifically talking about `EntityType` only, that looked like just an example. The `field.var.choices` is always an array of `ChoiceView` objects in either (since entity is just an extension of choice). The only difference is that in an `EntityType`, the `choices[i].data` value will be the entity itself, otherwise it will be the value of the field. You can also access the label via `choices[i].label`.